# Get IPv6 prefix using perl

Tags: perl, ipv6, prefix

I am trying to get the IPv6 Prefix from a given IPv6 Address given the prefix length.

I have already tried several modules (like Net::IP, Net::IPv6Addr, and Net::IPv6Address) but none seems to do exactly that.

Actually only Net::IPv6Address gives such a method but the result is not in IPv6 format.

For example:
The IPv6: *FE80:0202:B3FF:FE1E::/56* should give a prefix of *FE80:0202:B3FF:FE00::* but when I run this code:

```
use Net::IPv6Address;
my $IPv6Address = new Net::IPv6Address("FE80:0202:B3FF:FE1E::", 56);
my $prefix = $IPv6Address->prefix();
print $prefix;
```

I get *'fe800202b3fffe'* (Not the proper IPv6 format)...

I did the same in Java using the *com.googlecode.ipv6.IPv6Address* and *com.googlecode.ipv6.IPv6NetworkMask* libraries and it worked perfectly.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks to everyone in advance!

Comment: That return seems perfectly usable. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Do you just want the semicolons every 4 and append 0 to make it sets of 4 bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many modules that can do this. I would suggest [Net::Works](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aWorks) or [NetAddr::IP](https://metacpan.org/pod/NetAddr%3a%3aIP). With Net::Works:

```
use v5.16;

use Net::Works::Network;

my $network = Net::Works::Network->new_from_string( 
                 string => 'FE80:0202:B3FF:FE1E::/56' );
say $network->first;
```

This will output `fe80:202:b3ff:fe00::`.